# A theoretic question about cosine general solution.

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

I have to find the extremas of: $f(x)=x-\tan({x\over 2})$ .$(\pi\le x\le\pi)$

Last result is $\cos({x\over 2})=\pm{1\over \sqrt{2}}$.
I get that: ${x\over 2}=\pm{\pi\over 4}+2\pi k$ which derives: $x=\pm {\pi\over 2}+4\pi k$. My question is: should I write $x=\pm {\pi\over 2}+2\pi k$, or it is important to keep it $4$?
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: As $-\pi\le x\le \pi$, this is irrelevant. And there is no reason to change the $4$ into a $2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos\dfrac x2=\pm\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\iff\cos x=2\cos^2\dfrac x2-1=0$$

$x=(2m+1)\dfrac\pi2$ where $m$ is any integer

Comment: So it is after all $\pi m$?
So what am I to do from where I have arrived? Theoretically?

Comment: @Meitar, Whenever, you've reached $$\cos^2\dfrac x2=\dfrac12,$$ you use $\cos2y$ formula. Similarly for $\sin^2,\tan^2$

Comment: I know but I stick to my hypothetical question, for I might not think of an identity, and in that situation I would like to know what I ought to do.

Comment: @Meitar, For $\cos x/2=-1/\sqrt2,=-\cos\pi/4=\cos(\pi-\pi/4)\implies x/2=2m\pi\pm(\pi-\pi/4)$

Answer (score 2):

Your solution of $x/2 = \pm \pi/4 + 2 \pi k$ is equivalent only to $cos(x/2) = 1/\sqrt2$.

For $cos(x/2) = -1/\sqrt2$, $x/2 = \pm 3 \pi /4 + 2 \pi k$.

Combining them, we get

$x/2 = \pm \pi /4 + \pi k$

,or $x/2 = \pi /4 + \pi k/2$

,or $x = \pi /2 + \pi k$

PS: Try imagining/drawing angles in Quadrants of Cartesian coordinates if you are confused in any steps.